# What make the difference in 2 ways of while loop "php mysql_fetch_array"?

Tags: php

When I do the following:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query))){}
```

it is infinitive while loop.
But this one is not:

```
 $query = mysql_query($query);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){}
```

What is the difference between them? How does PHP execute?

Comment: In the first run, you are running the query every time `while` comes around, making it infinite.

Comment: How about the other one? When it calls $query, it links to mysql_query($query) and runs the query every time  when iterate..

Comment: No, it doesn't. In the second one `$query` is the result set from the query, so it doesn't run the query every time, just iterates through the result set.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: Not a problem ^^ Hopefully it helped clear it up for you.

Comment: Both are deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: [Don't use that code!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that you have a table `student` with following data

```
id  name
1   JD
2   Dev
3   Pallavi
```

Now if your `$query = "SELECT * FROM student"`

**CASE: 1**

`while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query))) { ... }`

For the first iteration the execution will be

1. mysql_query($query)
2. mysql_fetch_array(get_array_obtined_from_first_step)
3. Assign the current row to $row

In first step you get all 3 records of the student table. Then you fetch the Record Set in 3rd step you assign the row to $row.

Now as your 3 statements are in the while loop's condition, it will always be TRUE, because it will execute your query each time the loop is iterated, executing all the statements, making it infinite loop.

**CASE: 2**

`$query = mysql_query($query);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){}`

Here the query is executed **ONCE** and then each time the cursor is incremented assigning a single row to $row till the end of Result Set.

Thus when the end of Result Set is achieved it stops.

Comment: Nice detailed answer. ^^

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, PHP executes the query each time the loop enters new iteration, so the cursor (pointer to the row that goes forward each time you iterate over the result) does not move forward in the array of results. You get the whole bunch of same results each time and each time start from the beginning since the query is just executed.

In the second one your query is executed only once, and then PHP is iterating over the complete array of results while the cursor is moving forward and not being reset to zero on each iteration. That one is probably what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look for

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query))){}
```

In this, sql query execution is in `while loop`, means it's recursion itself, hence every time `$row` will get new data means `while loop` will not end anywhere.

```
 $query = mysql_query($query);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){}
```

In this case, you are executing `query` before `while loop`. Now you have specific set of result in your `$query` variable. `$query` has some limit like 0 or maximum record. Hence `loop` will stop execution at some point.

Answer (score 0):

**How a WHILE loop works:**

You need to understand when `while` loop stops iteration. A while loop looks like this :

```
while (expression) {
    statement
}
```

> At the beginning it will evaluate the expression first, if it returns `TRUE` (or which is equivalent to `TRUE`), then it will execute the statements inside the `{...}` block, otherwise, it will not execute anything. After it has finished the execution of that part, it will evaluate the expression again. If it returns `TRUE` again, it will execute scripts again, otherwise, it will stop here. This cycle will continue until the expression returns `FALSE`.

**Difference between two expressions:**

Now just look at your expression blocks

```
mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query))
```

It will always return `TRUE`, because, it is every time running the mysql_query and mysql_query returning result every time and mysql_fetch_array is always able to fetch the first row, which allows the loop to execute the statement block every time. That's how it becomes an infinite loop.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query)
```

Here you have run the query before (only once) and within the while expression you are fetching through the result. You get first row, 2nd row and so on every time you call `mysql_fetch_array()`. When you finish fetching the last row in the result set, `mysql_fetch_array()` will return `FALSE`, which will stop the iteration of `while` loop.

**Recommended Readings:**

1. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php
3. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

> Note : Consider switchig to `mysqli_query()` / `mysqli_fetch_array()` asap. The old functions are not going to be supported by PHP 7.